# Getting client system/network information

Tags: java, networking, applet, system

I have a web application that uses a Java applet to get my clients' system information by executing vbs code in Windows or basic commands in Linux, and network address too with java.net.InetAddress in order to log them into the webapp through ldap.

Due to Java applets will not be supported anymore shortly in the majority of browsers, I'm looking for another way of getting this information. Is there any way of doing it?

Thanks,
xavi

EDIT: Required information: System (OS, RAM, HD, IP, MAC) and network (username, machine name, domain name)

Answer (score 0):

All you basically need is some sort of module that can be downloaded from you application over the network, which would run locally on client machine and would do stuff you require.

Since Applets seems to a little outdated, there are other options as well.

You can use [JNLP](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/jnlp.html), it would work just like applets, but the whole package would be downloaded first and would require `JRE` on client machine to run it.

Comment: yes, this is what I'm looking for, that "module" that grants me the access to this data.
Regarding JNLP, I can't have the client executing a program each time I need this information.

Comment: I've added it to the question description

Comment: And do you require that info. each time a user interacts your system?

Comment: System information once a day, network information is for ldap (login) purposes, so I'd need it always.